# Data-title in Angular being truncated

Tags: angular, responsive

We use data-title to store table column headers for responsive design.  In tablet mode, the column headers are used to pivot a table.  Here is what an example template looks like.

```
        <td data-title="Email Address">{{results.emailAddress}}</td>
        <td data-title="{{translations.firstName}}">{{results.firstName}</td>
```

What is happening in Angular 6 is the first example with email address works but the label is hard coded - we need it translated.

The second example angular is turning that into:

```
         <td title="First Name">Tom</td>
```

Note it is dropping 'data-'.  This in turns messes with our design.  Can we get angular to stop changing the attribute name?

Comment: Dup of https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26406 Just use `[attr.data-title]` instead

Comment: Try with `[attr.data-title]`.

Comment: Thanks both.  It worked but it I had to tweak a bit to take off the interpolation symbols.  This works:  <td [attr.data-title]="translations.firstName">{{results.firstName}}</td>